# Help lines at specific symbolic coordinates

Tags: pgfplots

I tried to draw help lines at specific symbolic coordinates (x1, C(x1)) with the following code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xlabel={$x$},
        ylabel={$C$},
        axis lines=center,
        symbolic x coords={0,$x_1$,$x_2$,$x_3$,$x_4$},
        xmin={0},
        xmax={$x_4$},
        xtickmax={$x_3$},
        xtick distance=1,
        symbolic y coords={0,$C(x_1)$,$C(x_2)$,$C(x_3)$,$C(x_4)$},
        ymin={0},
        ymax={$C(x_4)$},
        ytickmax={$C(x_3)$},
        ytick distance=1]
        \addplot [color=red,mark=*] coordinates {($x_1$,{$C(x_1)$})};
        \draw [dashed,help lines] (0,{$C(x_1)$}) -| ($x_1$,0);
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

but the statement:

```
\draw [dashed,help lines] (0,{$C(x_1)$}) -| ($x_1$,0);
```

is wrong. My goal is to get:

[image]

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With symbolic coordinates you have to provide `axis cs` explicitly even if you use version 1.11 or newer.

```
\documentclass[margin=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xlabel={$x$},
        ylabel={$C$},
        axis lines=center,
        symbolic x coords={0,$x_1$,$x_2$,$x_3$,$x_4$},
        xmin={0},
        xmax={$x_4$},
        xtickmax={$x_3$},
        xtick distance=1,
        symbolic y coords={0,$C(x_1)$,$C(x_2)$,$C(x_3)$,$C(x_4)$},
        ymin={0},
        ymax={$C(x_4)$},
        ytickmax={$C(x_3)$},
        ytick distance=1]
        \addplot [color=red,mark=*] coordinates {($x_1$,{$C(x_1)$})};
        \draw [dashed,help lines] (axis cs:0,{$C(x_1)$}) -| (axis cs:$x_1$,0);
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

---

Without symbolic coordinates:

```
\documentclass[margin=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xlabel={$x$},
        ylabel={$y$},
        axis lines=center,
        xmin=0,xmax=4,
        xtick={1,...,3},
        xticklabel={$x_{\pgfmathprintnumber[precision=0]{\tick}}$},
        ymin=0,ymax=4,
        ytick={1,...,3},
        yticklabel={$C(x_{\pgfmathprintnumber[precision=0]{\tick}})$},
        ]
    \addplot [color=red,mark=*] coordinates {(1,1)};
    \draw [dashed,help lines] (0,1) -| (1,0);
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result is the same as above.